# firebase cloud functions for push notifications are not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions

in my flutter app, i have saved every devices token to a collection in firebase database and i wrote the code for firebase cloud functions so it sends a message(notification) for every user that subscribed to a topic and have their token is in the tokens collection but it doesnt send anything when i add something to the topic i subscribed them to, heres my cloud functions code using javascrpit in the index file:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().functions);

var newData;

exports.myTrigger = functions.firestore.document('messages/{messageId}').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    //

    if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log('No Devices');
        return;
    }

    newData = snapshot.data();

    const deviceIdTokens = await admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('messages')
        .get();

    var tokens = [];

    for (var tokened of deviceIdTokens.docs) {
        tokens.push(tokened.data().token);
    }
    var payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'Push Title',
            body: 'Push Body',
            sound: 'default',
        },
        data: {
            message: newData.message,
            click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
        },
    };

    try {
        const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
        console.log('Notification sent successfully');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

and heres my database structure
[image]

and the tokens collection :
[image]

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

trying his instead :

i should have written :
'''

```
const deviceIdTokens = await admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('tokens')
        .get()
```

'''

also for sending a message through the database i should have written "message" in the field  because i named the "data"'s key "message" :)